# Android Smartwatch sampling frequency

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, sampling

I've been using Sony Smartwatch 3 for recording accelerometer data on long time periods (8 hour on average). Below is the main code block: ax,ay and az are arraylists for storing the sensor values and ta is an arraylist with the corresponding timestamps.

```
private void startMeasurement() {
    mSensorManager = ((SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE));
    Log.d("lister", "listeners");
    Sensor accelerometerSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(SENS_ACCELEROMETER);

    // Register the listener
    if (mSensorManager != null) {
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometerSensor,25000);
    }
}

    @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if(event.sensor.getType() == SENS_ACCELEROMETER){
        ax.add(event.values[0]);
        ay.add(event.values[1]);
        az.add(event.values[2]);
        ta.add(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

}

public void write(){
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/sensor_data/" + timeStamp + ".csv");
    try{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter buffWriter = new BufferedWriter(fw,50*1024);
        for(int i=0;i<ax.size();i++){
            buffWriter.write(String.valueOf(ax.get(i)));
            buffWriter.write(",");
            buffWriter.write(String.valueOf(ay.get(i)));
            buffWriter.write(",");
            buffWriter.write(String.valueOf(az.get(i)));
            buffWriter.write(",");
            buffWriter.write(String.valueOf(ta.get(i)));
            buffWriter.write("\n");
        }
        buffWriter.flush();
        buffWriter.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

When taking a look at the time difference between samples I notice an increase in that time after some time recording the data. In the link below you can see the plot of the time difference between samples in seconds. 
[image]

Why is it happening that the difference jumps abruptly to 50 after some time recording?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up solving the problem by using Android's PowerManager and PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK. It consumes more battery but I really need the sampling frequency to be kept nearly constant.